# Multiply multiple columns conditionally by one column (easy in Excel)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
a   b   c   d   m1   m2 
3   2   2   2   5    4 
1   4   1   1   5    4   
3   2   2   3   5    4
```

I would like to multiply a and b for m1 and c and d for m2:

```
a   b   c   d   m1   m2 
15  10  8   8   5    4 
5   20  4   4   5    4   
15  10  8   12  5    4
```

Also retaining the original dataframe structure, This is fairly simple in Excel, but Pandas is proving complicated since if I try the first multiplication (m1) then the DF drops non used columns.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) with subset of columns defined by list of columns names:

```
df[['a', 'b']] = df[['a', 'b']].mul(df['m1'], axis=0)
df[['c', 'd']] = df[['c', 'd']].mul(df['m2'], axis=0)

print (df)
    a   b  c   d  m1  m2
0  15  10  8   8   5   4
1   5  20  4   4   5   4
2  15  10  8  12   5   4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using [`np.repeat`:](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html)

```
df.iloc[:, :4] *= np.repeat(df.iloc[:, 4:].values, 2, axis=1)

print(df)

    a   b  c   d  m1  m2
0  15  10  8   8   5   4
1   5  20  4   4   5   4
2  15  10  8  12   5   4
```